# How to activate the Keyboard when the button is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, keyboard

How to activate Keyboard when UIButton is Clicked.

I do have button When I clicked the button I need to activate the keyboard.

For default when i click for UITextField it will activated..

How to Implement when UIButton. Just a Button clicked need to show Keyboard.

@thanks to all. in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
     [myTextField becomeFirstRespoder];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

call `becomeFirstResponder`

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

on the field which will receive the input from the keyboard after it's shown.